# How can I schedule a Python script to run at a particular time every day, and make it a part of AWS Elastic Beanstalk application zip file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, scheduled-tasks

I've created an application using Dash and uploaded it to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. There is another python script which is responsible for updating the database (from which data is then extracted by the dashboard). I used apscheduler to schedule that script to run daily on my local machine but when I make that script a part of the zip package that I upload on AWSEB, it doesn't work. How can I fix this? I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: Task scheduler perhaps? You could convert a python file to an exe file using **pyinstaller** -  [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-python-script-to-exe-file/)

Comment: @HarshNagouda would a task scheduler be able to execute the script after it has been deployed on AWS EB?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to pull the "timed" Python script out into a dedicated lambda function.  With that in hand, you could trigger via AWS EventBridge on a cron style schedule.  You can define other inputs as well but that would get you very close.

Alternatively, I came across [this blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/schedule-elastic-beanstalk-stop-restart/) which may be of interest.  Good luck!